# Не могу запустить первую простую программу в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Проблемы с шагом make. Все, в чем я думаю они могут заключаться есть на слайдах.

Вот код:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QLabel text("Hi! It's me");
    text.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: `qmake` передан параметр `spec` 32-битной версии, а вам нужен для 64-битной.

Answer (score 1):

Окно "Проекты" - **Этапы сборки** - **Make: В комплекте не задан компилятор**

Погляди внимательно в "Инструменты -> Параметры... -> Сборка и запуск -> Комплекты" в используемом комплекте строку "Компилятор:", наверняка пустая.

Comment: Действительно пусто. Напротив компилятор нажал "управление" и меня перевело на вкладку "компиляторы" (первый слайд в вопросе). Что здесь делать?

Comment: Там я уже не могу определённо сказать, что надо делать, потому что никогда не использовал Qt Creator в связке с компиляторами Microsoft Visual. Проще всего в данном случае, как мне кажется, переустановить заново Qt Creator с компилятором MinGW.